# Urn draw probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics

can you help me on this?

An urn contains $7$ balls, $4$ of which are black and the rest white.

1) Starting with all 7 balls in the urn, balls are drawn randomly with replacement. Find the probability that among the first $5$ balls which are drawn

a. $2$ of them are white. 
b. at least 3 of them are black.

For 1.a  I used Binomial distribution,but I don't understand why probability of success (p=3/7) I thought that was p=1/2 because it is black or it is not so there is 1 outcomes out of 2. Can you explain me this? Also in question b) I was checking and there is only 4 black balls, which means that I have to sum the probabilities of 3 blacks and 4 blacks am I right?

For 1.b  I used again Binomial Distribution so I did: P(X=3)+P(X=4) so : (5 3) (4/7)^3 (3/7)^2 + (5 4) (4/7)^4 (3/7)^1 Can you let me know if I did it right?

2)  Starting with all 7 balls in the urn, balls are drawn randomly without replacement until all 3 white balls are found. What is the probability that the third white ball is found on the

a. fourth attempt? 
b. seventh attempt?

For 2.a there can be combinations:

wwbw p=3/7*2/6*4/5*1/4=1/35
wbww& p=3/7*4/6*2/5*1/4=1/35
bwww p=4/7*3/6*2/5*1/4=1/35

P=3/35, right?

for 2.b is there a way to do this without thinking in all possible combinations, as in the question above?

Many thanks.

Comment: We can help you, but will feel more inspired to do so if you show how much you've helped yourself.  What have you tried?  How far have you gotten?  What are your thoughts? Where are you having difficulties? Please don't just post a problem and expect someone to solve it all for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for 1a) is $\binom{5}{2}\frac{3}{7}^2\frac{4}{7}^3$. This is an application of binomial theorem. Do you see how I made this calculation?

For 1b) you need to sum up the probabilities of exactly 3 black, exactly 4 black, and exactly 5 black.

Comment: I understood and  I used Binomial distribution,but I don't understand why probability of success (p=3/7) I thought that was p=1/2 because it is black or it is not so there is 1 outcomes out of 2. Can you explain me this?
 Also in question b) I was checking and there is only 4 black balls, which means that I have to sum the probabilities of 3 blacks and 4 blacks am I right?

Comment: And following your idea p should be 4/7 because there are 4black balls  out of 7 total balls. So the answer should be (5 2) (4/7)^2(3/7)^3 right? Thank you

Comment: @user290335 , $p = 3/7$ because $3$ of $7$ balls are *white* , which is what you are counting (vis "2 of them are white")

Comment: Yes, you are right. My confusion. I thought there were two blacks. Thanks.

Comment: Hi can you check if I am thinking in the right way? for the question b) at least 3 balls are black, I used again Binomial Distribution so I did: P(X=3)=P(X=4) so : (5 3) (4/7)^3 (3/7)^2 + (5 4) (4/7)^4 (3/7)^1 Can you let me know if I did it right? thank you